# How do I unwrap an optional within a struct and use an if statement to print the optional?

Tags: swift, if-statement, struct, option-type

I am getting an error message for my use of `nil`, and I am confused on how to properly unwrap the optional while placing it in an `if` statement to print if it is non-`nil`.

The following is my code:

```swift
struct DatingProfile{
  var Name: String
  var Age: Int
  var City: String
  var FavoriteMovie: String? 
  var Hobbies: String?   
}

  let myDatingProfile = DatingProfile(
    Name: "William",
    Age: 30,
    City: "North Hollywood",
    FavoriteMovie: nil,
    Hobbies: "Basketball"
  )

  if let myFavoriteMovie = FavoriteMovie = nil {
    print("\(Name) does not have a favorite movie")    
  } else {  
    print(myDatingProfile.FavoriteMovie)
  }      
}
```

The following is an error log:

```
exit status 1
main.swift:12:26: error: use of unresolved identifier 'FavoriteMovie'
if let myFavoriteMovie = FavoriteMovie = nil{
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.swift:13:12: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Name'
  print("\(Name) does not have a favorite movie")
           ^~~~
main.swift:17:11: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
    print(myDatingProfile.FavoriteMovie)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.swift:17:27: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
    print(myDatingProfile.FavoriteMovie)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        ?? <#default value#>
main.swift:17:27: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
    print(myDatingProfile.FavoriteMovie)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       !
main.swift:17:27: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
    print(myDatingProfile.FavoriteMovie)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        as Any
main.swift:20:1: error: extraneous '}' at top level
}
^
```

Comment: Although the posted answers are sufficient to resolve your issue, I'd say that `if let myFavoriteMovie = FavoriteMovie = nil`  is not how to do it. Read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html (Optional binding).

Comment: FYI - it is standard practice that class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters. Variable, method, and case names start with lowercase letters.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to throw a computed var in your struct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access properties of a struct via the instance of the struct. You can only use the property names directly inside instance methods of that struct.

```
if let myFavoriteMovie = myDatingProfile.FavoriteMovie {
  print(myFavoriteMovie)
} else {
    print("\(myDatingProfile.Name) does not have a favorite movie")
}
```

You should also be conforming to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names and properties (`city`, `name`, `favoriteMovie`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, and please use `camelCase` for swift properties.
Also, you should *really* consider reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/). Start from [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html).

```swift
struct DatingProfile {
  var name: String
  var age: Int
  var city: String
  var favoriteMovie: String? 
  var hobbies: String?
}

let myDatingProfile = DatingProfile(
  name: "William",
  age: 30,
  city: "North Hollywood",
  favoriteMovie: nil,
  hobbies: "Basketball"
)

// Use if-let syntax
if let myFavoriteMovie = myDatingProfile.favoriteMovie {
  print(myFavoriteMovie)
} else {
  print("\(myDatingProfile.name) does not have a favorite movie")    
}

// Or use guard-let syntax
guard let myFavoriteMovie = myDatingProfile.favoriteMovie else {
  print("\(myDatingProfile.name) does not have a favorite movie")
  return
}
print(myFavoriteMovie)
```